# Set Model Field as Required in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Django doesn't enforce NOT NULL at the model/database level. device_serial is neither supposed to have blank '' nor null

```
class Device(models.Model):
       device_serial = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
       ....etc
```

The statement below works totally fine! I expect it to fail because device_serial is required. It shouldn't accept empty string ''

```
Device.objects.create(device_serial='')
```

How can I make a field required at the model / database level? What could I possibly be doing wrong here? I don't see where did I go wrong. I tried ''.strp() to convert empty string to None but it didn't work

Comment: An empty string is not NULL, try passing None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mohd's answer worked! Alternatively, a check constraint at the DB level worked as well.

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(check=~models.Q(device_serial=''), name='chk_device_device_serial')
    ]
```

Comment: This is the most reliable answer. It enforces the constraint at the database level, so it works in cases where `save()` doesn't get called (e.g. when using bulk_update). The `constraints` feature was added in Django 2.2. For older versions, you can add the database constraint using raw sql in a handmade migration.

Comment: Blog post with more info [Django’s Field Choices Don’t Constrain Your Data](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/22/djangos-field-choices-dont-constrain-your-data/)

Answer (score 3):

As far as the database is concerned, it only allows **null/not null** which is handled by `null=True/False` and defaults to `False`. The `blank=True/False` is for admin page only.

The string `''` is not considered null which is why it is accepted by the database when you have `null=False` constraint.

If you want to to avoid blank strings in database level you can override `save()` on the model itself and raise an exception when `device_serial` is set to an empty string, for example:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Device(models.Model):
    device_serial = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.device_serial == '':
            raise ValidationError('device_serial cannot be empty')
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now when you try to create an object with empty string (which calls `save()`), the following exception will be raised:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['device_serial cannot be empty']
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked but I found a workaround. Setting default=None forces empty string to be null which makes create() to fail.... device_serial = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True, default=None)

Comment: Glad it did!, I don't think setting `default=None` would force the empty string to be null. Are you sure you didn't override `save()` and there is no object saved with empty string `device_serial`? Because `unique=True` constraint would raise an exception then

Comment: Akh my bad! Correct. I hard-coded Device.objects.create(device_serial=None) and forgot to take it out. It didn't work. Going back to your solution
'

Answer (score 0):

In my case was enough by setting `default=None` in field definition.

In your case:

```
class Device(models.Model):
       device_serial = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True, default=None)
```

I've removed `null=False` and `blank=False` due it's the default value.